# htaccess redirect all links from a domain to a particular URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am new to Apache. I want to redirect all the links from a domain to a particular file  domain.com/welcome.html before visit any other page.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that if the user comes from some domain to your site, to show a particular page? For instance, if they came from google, they would be taken to google.html? Or do you mean that if they visit your site, they will first be taken to your welcome page?

Comment: taken to the welcome page first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using mod_rewrite:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

which is the proper mechanism to redirect incoming traffic to a particular page based on a variety of conditions (incl referrer url, user agent, etc).

.htaccess is about authorization of resources, not redirection between resources.